# how to convert <script> tag in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As part of my application, I have a  tag as shown below. Do I want to know how I should convert it in react?

can I seperate it is a javascript file and load that in this file? if answer is yes, can you show me how?

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
  <section class="abcContainer">
        <div class="card border-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 20rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Toolbox</div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="col col-6">
                    <ul class="ml4 js-sortable-copy sortable list flex flex-column list-reset" aria-dropeffect="move">
                        <li class="p1 mb1 yellow bg-maroon" style="position: relative; z-index: 10" draggable="true" role="option" aria-grabbed="false">Item 1</li>
                        <li class="p1 mb1 yellow bg-maroon" style="position: relative; z-index: 10" draggable="true" role="option" aria-grabbed="false">Item 2</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <div class="col col-6">
                <h2 class="h4 mt1">Copy items here</h2>
                <ul class="p2 border maroon border-maroon js-sortable-copy-target sortable list flex flex-column list-reset" aria-dropeffect="move"></ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>


    <script>
        sortable('.js-sortable-copy', {
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            copy: true,
            acceptFrom: false,
            placeholderClass: 'mb1 bg-navy border border-yellow',
        });
        sortable('.js-sortable-copy-target', {
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            acceptFrom: '.js-sortable-copy,.js-sortable-copy-target',
            placeholderClass: 'mb1 border border-maroon',
        });
        sortable('.js-grid', {
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            placeholderClass: 'col col-4 border border-maroon'
        });
    </script>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call them in `componentDidMount` hook:

```
mySortable() {
  // sortable() scripts
}

componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('onload', this.mySortable)
}
```

And then make sure to remove the listener in `componentWillUnmount` hook:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener('onload', this.mySortable)
}
```

Comment: should I write it in App.js after class App extends Component?

Comment: in mysortable should I write the script with <script> tag or without. can you edit ur answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would check to see if there is an npm package for the library you are using in that script then import it for that component. For instance, if this is sortable.js then https://www.npmjs.com/package/sortablejs. This makes things more modular.

Otherwise, I  would create a separate file with the functions and import them and attach them to which elements need to use them by running the data/elements through the function within a lifecycle method (componentDidMount or render [depending]) or using attributes like onHover, onClick, etc.

If they are functions for the entire web application copy the script tag into your index.html file.

Comment: I already did that. this script is require inside the html file.